# ¿Como logro buscar un elemento en específico dentro de un HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

El programa trata sencillamente de que el usuario tiene dos opciones:

-Sí escoge la primera le dará la opción de registrarse a un listado para ser jurado de votación (en esta opción no ocurre ningún  inconveniente)

-Sí escoge la otra opción le otorgará al usuario poder buscarse entre el listado de quienes son los jurados para así ver si está en ese listado (aquí es donde ocurre el problema).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class exepciones {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, String> personas_elegidas = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //Atributos
    private String personas;
    private String identificador;
    byte respuesta;

    //getter 
    public String getPersonas(){
        return personas;
    }

    public String getIdentificador(){
        return identificador;
    }    

    //setter
    public String setPersonas(String newpersona){
      this.personas = newpersona;
      return newpersona;
    }
    public String setIndentificador (String newidentificador){
        this.identificador = newidentificador;
        return newidentificador;
    }

    //Metodo donde están las personas elegidas para jurados y para poder registrar al usuario
    public void registro ( String nombre, String id){
        personas_elegidas.put(id, nombre);
            personas_elegidas.put("1020321988", "Luís Fernando Barbosa Gutierrez" );
            personas_elegidas.put("172893019200", "Sofía Valentina Díaz Cifuente");
            personas_elegidas.put("7389283782", "Violeta Sofia de Patagonía Torres");
            personas_elegidas.put("8293661029", "Noriel Ramírez Gutierrez De León");
            personas_elegidas.put("61728394009", "Andres Felipe Castro Costeras");
            personas_elegidas.put("1728883901", "Junior Felipe Beníte Castillo");
            personas_elegidas.put("1627888399", "Prismo Tamarí Álvarez Uribe");
            personas_elegidas.put("1729322300", "Johan David Florez Hernández");
            personas_elegidas.put("1112638101", "Pipe Felipe López Zambrano");
            personas_elegidas.put("8293715260", "Javier Galán Rodríguez Gutierrez ");
            personas_elegidas.put("2819093765", "Ernezto Emanuel Trujillo Torres ");
            personas_elegidas.put("1728938801", "Daniel Felipe Diaz Cifuentes");
            personas_elegidas.put("17280382709", "Oscar Manuel García Peréz");
            personas_elegidas.put("8192086678", "Noriega Savana Del Campo");
            personas_elegidas.put("1829300936", "Ernesto Otoniel De La Cruz");
            personas_elegidas.put("1782903985", "Zucumi David Leyva Araujo");
            personas_elegidas.put("1028396080", "Fernado Otoniel Carazamvanbiche ");
            personas_elegidas.put("7293017204", "Navarro Navarretez Vazques Rojas");
            personas_elegidas.put("1234567890", "Daniela Sofía Torres Toronjo");

    }

    public void verificador () {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Digite que opción desea ejecutar:");
        System.out.println("1 -----> Registrarse para jurado de votación");
        System.out.println("2 -----> Verificar sí soy jurado de votación");
        try{  
            respuesta = entrada.nextByte();
            entrada.nextLine();
        }
        catch (Exception l) {
            System.out.println("Por favor, verifique sí digitó el número correspondiente");
        }
        if (respuesta == 1) {
            System.out.println("Por favor, digite su numero de identificación y su nombre para registrarlo");
            System.out.println("-----Nombre Completo: ");
            String newpersona = entrada.nextLine();  
            System.out.println("-----Número de identificación: ");
            String newindentificador = entrada.next();
                while (newindentificador.length() != 10 ) {
                    System.out.println("El número de identificación es invalido, debe tener 10 números");
                    newindentificador = entrada.next();
                } 
            registro( setPersonas(newpersona), setIndentificador(newindentificador));
            System.out.println("-----¡Registro completado!-----");
            for (String i: personas_elegidas.keySet()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Número de identificació: " + i + "|Nombre completo: " + personas_elegidas.get(i));
                
            }
        }   

        //Aquí es donde se presentó el inconveniente
        if (respuesta == 2) {
            System.out.println("Digita su numero de identificación para hacer la respectiva busqueda");
            System.out.println("-----Número de identificación: ");
            String newindentificador = entrada.next();//Se guarda en una variable lo que se digita

         /*Posteriormente se evalua con el metodo containsKey() si lo que digitó el usuario está 
         guardado (o al menos así pienso yo)*/
            Boolean r2 = personas_elegidas.containsKey(newindentificador);
            if (r2 == true) {
                System.out.println("Su número de identificación si se encuentra en la base de datos");
                System.out.println("Le pedimos que asísta mañana a su respectiva urna :) ");
                System.out.println("Número de identificación: " + newindentificador + "|Nombre completo: "+ personas_elegidas.get(newindentificador));
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Su número no se encuentra en la base de datos...");
            }
        }  
    }
```

Al final, cuando marco para la segunda opción y digito algún número de identificación que evidentemente está guardado dentro del metodo registro() para ver si procede a ejecutar la condicional if (r2 == true)...Me lo salta y no entiendo el por qué hace eso.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Para empezar, tus `if` deberían estar dentro del bloque `try`. Luego, danos un ejemplo de los datos con los que estás trabajando cuya condición dices que no se cumple o da problemas.

Comment: Bueno, escribo el último número de identificación que aparece en el metodo registro() que es "1234567890".

Comment: Ejecuto el programa, le doy a la segunda opción, escribo aquel número que acabe de mencionar, pero aunque aquel número este evidentemente en el listado del metodo registro() no me lo capta